# Install ipad application on additional device

Tags: iphone, ipad, distribution, provisioning

Is it possible for me to create a ipad application and install it on a device that is located at a remote location? Can this be done if I have its device id?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Ad Hoc distribution using that device id and install it via iTunes attached to a computer at that remote location.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. Pushing applications to an iPad is not possible.

Comment: Even if I have a developers subscription? Can't I add it as an additional device?